# Make bootstrap vertical navigation collapsible on visiting that link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building jquery vertical menu navigation, there are some links to pages on `<li> <a>` tags, what i want is that whenever a link is clicked then on page load that sub menu is active and his parent menu is collapsed and others are closed.

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index2.html">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></scrip>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
          $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
          $(this).next().slideToggle();
          $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
        }
      });
    });
```

and css stuff,

```
#nav {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a.active {
    background: #999;
    color: #fff;
}
#nav li ul {
    display: none; // used to hide sub-menus
}
#nav li ul li a {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background: #ececec;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
```

I want that when user clicks on sub-item 2 a than on that page load the item 2 menu is collapsed opened and others are closed. i have write above code, but not working as i expecting...

here is the [Jssfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Taqi_Shah/LzsLrL12/)

Comment: Can we see this in action or can you make a fiddle of it?

Comment: @ShaunLoftin i have updated the question, could you review it.

Comment: will have to compare menu item href to the url or have server code set an active class. Javascript doesn't maintain state when load a new page

Comment: What does this have to do with twitter-bootstrap? Nothing in your code has any reference to bootstrap at all.